# I cannot convert date and time to Carbon instance in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, php-carbon

I am trying to create `Carbon` instance from different `$date` and `$time` variables. I am using following code right now.

```
$user->created_at = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($entry->Date." ".$entry->Time);
```

But I am getting this error.

```
In Carbon.php line 547:

DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (18/08/2017 10:49:50) at position 0 (1): Unexpected character
```

I also tried removing `$time` variable to check if it works with just `$date` variable or not. But In that case too, I am getting this error:

```
In Carbon.php line 547:

DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (18/08/2017) at position 0 (1): Unexpected character
```

I also tried trimming out `"` using `trim()` function to make sure that the character that Carbon cannot understand is not `"`. But it's giving me the same output.

How can I solve this error? I tried to find on the internet and other stack overflow questions and they suggested me to update my **Carbon** package and I did. But still, it's giving me the same error. I can't figure out what's wrong with the code.

**UPDATE**: I also tried with `strtotime($entry->Date);` but still, Same error!

Comment: check if there is a hidden character at the start of your string

Comment: I checked using `echo($entry->Date);` but looks like there are no hidden characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this,

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $entry->Date.' '.$entry->Time);
```

I hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

Create a timestamp of date and time . After that you can parse them using Carbon

```
$timestamp = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($entry->Date. $entry->Time);
$dateTime=date('d/m/Y h:i:s',$timestamp);
Carbon::parse($dateTime);
```